# what are the Drawbacks of using className or id to access dom elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to measure a lot of svg paths that I mapped over (with `element.getTotalLength()`). I know the `id` of each `<path>` but don't have any other way to access them. Are there any issues or pitfalls I should expect if I use something like `document.querySelector("#a-01").getTotalLength()` to measure them? 
Or is there a better way to access these elements?

Comment: how many paths and how often do you think your app would call such method? also i am pretty sure Safari does not support it unless it changed recently

Comment: @SergeyRudenko safari doesn't support querySelector on paths? have about 200-300 elements....

Comment: yeah it’s not supported based on canIUse.com, generally speaking it is better to avoid direct dom access with modern frameworks, but depending on your use case it can be ok. I would create something like HTML live collection and ran a loop across elements. In case Safari is critical i am afraid you would need a custom solution

Comment: @SergeyRudenko https://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector seems supported

Comment: i meant svg method you intended to use:)